# Variable value is kept into next iteration of "for" loop?

Tags: python

Take the pseudocode below for example:

Python keeps the previous value for `x`, so if `get_sum()` fails, the conditional is still checked using the previous value of `x`.
Is this because python for loop doesn't introduce a new scope and is it ok to simply del the object at the end of each iteration?

```
for number in number_list:
    try:
        x = get_sum()
    except:
        ....

    if x > 100:
        do something
```

Comment: You can always write: `x = None; x = get_sum()` and check for `None` later.

Comment: " Is this because python for loop doesnt introduce new scope and is it ok to simply del the object at the end of each iteration?" Yes, Python does not have block scope, `x` is just a global variable here (or if it is in a function, a local variable, but local to the function not to a the block). Note, you don't `del` objects, you `del` *variables*

Comment: But if you *do* `del x` then `x > 100` will throw a `NameError` (or `UnboundLocal` if you are in a local scope...)

Comment: I know it's pseudocode, but this warning is important anyways: **Never** use a bare `except`! Except **only** the errors you expect to happen!

Answer (score 2):

Every variable in python is created in the scope of their respective functions and classes rather than at different levels of indentation, or in for loops or while loops. There's no block scope in python like there is in java.

If you need x to not retain its old value, you can always set `x = None` in your except clause and have a conditional catch it later on. If i'm misinterpreting your question please leave a comment